# I am trying to auto rotate an image after ever 5 seconds from css

Tags: css

I am trying to auto rotate an image after ever 5 seconds from css. My code is working but only on hover but I want on both hover and without hover. So far I have done is given below.

```
.circle-border:hover {
-webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(720deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(720deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(720deg);
    transform: rotate(720deg);
    transition: transform 0.9s ease 0.3s;
}

<div class="circle-border">
        <img class="img-circle" src="images/web.jpg" alt="service 1">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `transition-delay:5s;`

Comment: This is not possible using only css.You can use JS.

Comment: put your html code here.

Comment: Code updated. Html code shared.

Comment: how I can use animation? Please share.. Thanks

Comment: @AnkithAmtange please can I have an example code in my code if possible please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an **animation** not a transtion.

[**CSS Animations @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation)

This animation is 6s long but the rotation only takes place in the last 1/6th of the duration....which gives us a 1s animation every 5 seconds.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #663399;
  margin: 1em auto;
  -webkit-animation-name: spinner;
  animation-name: spinner;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spinner {
  83.33% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes spinner {
  83.33% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used Javascrit to do it  however it's still can made with css alone
but maybe usefull, hope it can help

```js
var circle = document.getElementById("test");
if (circle.classList.contains("move")) {
    setInterval(function () {
        "use strict";
        circle.classList.add("move");
    }, 2000);
    setInterval(function () {
        "use strict";
        circle.classList.remove("move");
    }, 5000);
    
}
```

```css
.circle-border {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#F00;
    
  }
  .move {
    animation: circle .9s ease 1;
  }
  .circle-border:hover {
-webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(720deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(720deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(720deg);
    transform: rotate(720deg);
    transition: transform 0.9s ease 0.3s;
}

@keyframes circle {
  0% {transform:rotate(0)}
  100% { transform:rotate(720deg)}
}
```

```html
<div id="test" class="circle-border move">

</div>
```